# How can I add shared drives to Raspberry PI 3?

Tags: mount, samba, share

So I have been given this LINK: **`\\HDD011\01_Presentaion\06_New_1`** .

I know this link is from a network shared drive here at my job.

As a side project, I've been asked to make this link available to our Raspberry Pi(that runs on Raspbian) on our wall for some presentation to run there.
I have read that `samba` should be able to do just what I need but I don't really know how to implement it.

So how can I make this link available there all the time ?
What options do I have ?

Comment: try here https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40974/access-network-samba-share-from-pi-client

Answer (score 3):

Create a mountpoint for your share:

```
sudo mkdir /media/winshare
sudo chown pi:pi /media/winshare
```

Create a smbcred file:

```
nano /home/pi/.smbcred
```

Write the following into it (replace username and password) :

```
username=username
password=paswword
```

Save (CTRL-O) and exit (CTRL-X).

The dot at the beginning of the filename indicates a hidden file. Hidden files can be shown with

```
 ls -la
```

Finally add following line to /etc/fstab:

```
//HDD011/01_Presentaion/06_New_1 /media/winshare cifs x-systemd.automount,users,credentials=/home/pi/.smbcred 0 0
```

/media/winshare will appear as regular folder and you can now read and write to it.

Comment: You should set `chmod 600 /home/pi/.smbcred`. Don't know, but network filesystem `cifs` is available by default?

Comment: Thanks you for the answer. When I add the line to /etc/fstab I get this error :             -bash: //HDD011/01_Presentaion/06_New_1: No such file or directory'

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the changes to be permanent you can use

```
sudo mount -t cifs //HDD011/01_Presentaion/06_New_1 /media/winshare -o username=share_username,iocharset=utf8,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777
```

where share_username is the username that you have to use to sign in.