# Rpi to read windows and SAMBA folder files

Tags: raspbian, windows, samba

I want to use a NEW RPi 3b+ to play music files hosted on another RPi and Windows a PC. 
The RPi with media files runs a SAMBA server with a 4TB HDD with all music and other files on it. The RPi also acts as a NAS drive.

The NEW RPi will also cycle through web pages (using Chromium with a plugin) from 3 webservers on my LAN (Also RPi's - monitoring Solar production and power usage etc)

Now the question:
On the NEW PRi, Besides VLC Media Player, and speakers,  what software do I need to install and configure to be able to connect and read any SAMBA server AND any Windows shared folders?

Thanks for the help

Frits

Answer (score 2):

If you want provide files to clients then you want Windows as SMB **SERVER**:

[image]

If you want your RPi to access to an SMB server, then you want RPi as SMB **CLIENT** (testparm, smbclient, nmblookup ... and other binary are provided when you install [samba package](https://packages.debian.org/stretch/samba)):

[image]

Adapt according to your needs ...

If you want to use a name in place of an IP address for the network access, you must configure a domain name server.

Comment: Ephemeral,  Thanks a lot. Got it working now.
Mounting works fine in fstab.

https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40974/access-network-samba-share-from-pi-client

How can I automate :
sudo mount -a.

I tried adding in fstab, but mapping does does happen

Comment: @user4742250? You're welcome. You want to auto-mount at RPi and network connectivity starts-up ?

Comment: For some or other reason the RPi hangs after a day or two continues music play.

I have managed to schedule a reboot in cron to happen at midnight.
Directly after that I have also added a task to map the drive.

I am unable to create a cron task to start playing the shortcut that is on my desktop.

How do I do that?