# Is it possible to write to file located in windows directory using Node-Red via ssh?

Tags: ssh, raspberry-pi-desktop, readwrite, nodered

I log into my raspberry pi via ssh. I am trying to read and write to a file located in my C drive using Node-Red. However when I deploy the Node-red task, the file that I amend is not located in the C drive directory I asked it to read and write too.
Instead, when I log into the raspberry pi via its desktop (without ssh) I find the file I tried to amend located in the home/pi directory.

Why is this the case? Can I not do this operation via ssh? Does ssh just provide access to the raspberry pi and that's it?
I have seen a Youtube video showing someone reading and writing to a windows directory. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=iOAyLQD0Wro&t=58s
Or is this not done using a raspberry pi?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your windows computer, use [Windows folder sharing](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/file-sharing-over-a-network-in-windows-10-b58704b2-f53a-4b82-7bc1-80f9994725bf) to share your destination folder

Then [mount this shared folder](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/40974/access-network-samba-share-from-pi-client) on your raspberry pi

Finally, instruct node-red to write to the windows shared folder at the location you have mounted it in your raspberry pi

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Shodan I managed to figure it out.

I followed this tutorial (https://pimylifeup.com/raspberry-pi-samba/) to install samba and set up a sharing network between my windows pc and pi.
This works for my current needs.